# How to center mathematical expression inside multi-line closed brackets?

Tags: tex

How could I center the two lines inside the brackets. The code so far is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{equation}
x_{t}^{\ast }(n)=
\left\{\!\begin{aligned}  
& \hfil {x_{t}}\\
\hfil & {0,\text{ otherwise}}         
\end{aligned}\right\}
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of options:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,eqparbox,xparse}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34412/5764
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\eqmathbox}{o O{c} m}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}
    {\def\eqmathbox@##1##2{\eqmakebox[#1][#2]{$##1##2$}}}
    {\def\eqmathbox@##1##2{\eqmakebox{$##1##2$}}}
  \mathpalette\eqmathbox@{#3}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  x_t^* (n) =
    \left\{\begin{array}{@{} c @{}}
      x_t \\
      0, \text{ otherwise}
    \end{array}\right\}
\]

\[
  x_t^* (n) =
    \left\{\begin{aligned}
      \eqmathbox[cond]{x_t} \\
      \eqmathbox[cond]{0, \text{ otherwise}}
    \end{aligned}\right\}
\]

\end{document}
```

The first uses an `array` with a single, `c`entred column. The second uses `aligned` and sets each entry inside an `\eqmathbox[<tag>]` with the same `<tag>`. [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox) then finds the maximum width of those elements with the same `<tag>`, and sets each element inside a box of that width (default `<align>`ment is `c`entred `\eqmathbox[<tag>][<align>]{<stuff>}`).